# add product to cart in woocommerce from outside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i've figured out that is possible to add a product to cart with these lines:

`global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);`

My question is, how to add a product to cart from outside? I have a simple php site, just want to delegate the sales to wordpress/woocommerce. 
Can i do it with the Api?
Can you point me in th right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a product to the cart from outside of wordpress you can simply add a query on the end of your url, it will need to look like this:

http://YOURWEBSITE/?add-to-cart=PRODUCTID

where `PRODUCTID` is the id of the product you want to add to your cart.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Sure, that's usefull, thank you very much. Just have one more trouble: The user must be able to add more than one item, and them redirect them to the checkout page.

Comment: u can also add ?quantity to the end of the above

Comment: great! what about to add differents product_id at the same click? would you do an ajax call or something like to iterate over the products 'array' to handle this? thank you in advnce